# Why I am getting this error code 500 despite sending all data right?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I am creating a python application which could add amazon items to the cart. But Amazon is responding to the request with an internal server error. I have made the same application as a javascript extension and it worked proving that the data sent was correct. So I am curious to find out why despite sending all the data correct, the server is responding differently to both applications. I have changed cookies in the below code for obvious reasons.Here are both the codes:
Javascript Code:

```
  data = 'dealId='+dealid+'&itemId='+asin+'&clientId=goldbox_mobile_pc'
  resp = "";

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.amazon.in/gp/deal/ajax/v2/claimDeal.html',
    type: 'post',
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function (x) {
            x.setRequestHeader("x-csrftoken", token);
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
      console.log(data)
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
  });
```

```
import requests
from requests.cookies import cookiejar_from_dict
#creating a session
session = requests.Session()
#getting the csrf token. function is not shown in this code but it exists
csrf=getCsrf()
#sending cookies for loggging in
session.cookies={"ubid-acbin":"261-47212800-4332916","x-acbin":"unH4
KUpytXNLkPMKJm0DvSdgqMm@Gc?JDIwN2SJ@wmBDeBirSx6mHDHnHcljzy7rJ"}
session.cookies = cookiejar_from_dict(session.cookies)
#setting headers
session.headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.61 Safari/537.36',
"x-csrftoken": csrf
}
#sending request
m=session.post('https://www.amazon.in/gp/deal/ajax/v2/claimDeal.html', data='dealId=d9ca05bf&itemId=B086Z933SS&clientId=goldbox_mobile_pc')
print(m.content)
```

Comment: try `console.log(jqXhr)` in `error` and see if there's any useful info there about the error

Comment: The error is not in javascript, it is in the python code

Comment: Oh ... sorry - misunderstood which one worked and which one didn't ... check the request headers in the code that works (browser developer tools helps here)... there's definitely headers a browser is sending that your pythin code isn't ... Perhaps amazon requires `Host`, `Origin`, `Referer` (note the bad spelling of Referer) or even `Accept` and `Accept-Encoding` and `Accept-Language`